# Django, Celery Supervisor: Secret Key Error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I have a django 1.11.4, python3.5, gunicorn 19.7.1 server with supervisor, redis 2.10.6 and celery 4.1.0.

My File structure is like so:

```
samy_python
├── celery.py
├── __init__.py
├── settings
├── urls.py
├── wsgi.py
website
├── static
├── templates
├── samy
|    ├── samy_firebase.py
|    ├── tasks.py
├── views.py
```

I get my secret with:

```
# settings.py
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("secret_KEY")
```

My supervisor conf file for celery is:

```
[program:gunicorn]

....
environment = secret_KEY="12345"
.....

[program:celery]
directory=/home/username/Projects/samy/samy_python
command=/home/username/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/bin/celery --app=samy_python.celery.app worker -B -l info
user=username
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/celery.log
autostart=false
autorestart=false
startsecs=10
```

My Celery File:

```
# celery.py

from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('myapp.celery.py')

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "samy_python.settings")

# Celery App
# TODO
# [START Celery App]
app = Celery('samy_python')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

# [END Celery App]
```

My init file:

```
# __init__.py

from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

The Configuration in my settings.py file for celery:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Where the error could be coming from is in my settings.py file I use an env variable to set the environment. (Production, Dev, or Test):

```
DEBUG = False
DJANGO_TESTING = False
DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT = False
DJANGO_ENV = os.environ.get('DJANGO_ENV')

if DJANGO_ENV == 'DJANGO_TESTING':
    DJANGO_TESTING = True
elif DJANGO_ENV == 'DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT':
    DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT = True
```

Then I set the firebase credentials and Google Api credentials. I then get the credentials from within, for example, samy_firebase.py with:

```
from django.conf import settings
if settings.DJANGO_TESTING == True:
    logger.info('Firebase Config: Test DB')
```

I'm not sure if the last part is relevant or not, but here is the error that I keep receiving:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'data'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
        _main()
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 326, in main
        cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in execute_from_commandline
        super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 281, in execute_from_commandline
        return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 480, in handle_argv
        return self.execute(command, argv)
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 412, in execute
        ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 219, in run_from_argv
        *self.parse_options(prog_name, argv, command))
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 403, in parse_options
        self.parser = self.create_parser(prog_name, command)
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 419, in create_parser
        self.add_arguments(parser)
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 275, in add_arguments
        default=conf.worker_state_db,
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
        return self[k]
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 431, in __getitem__
        return getitem(k)
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 280, in __getitem__
        return mapping[_key]
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/collections/__init__.py", line 982, in __getitem__
        if key in self.data:
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
        value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 148, in data
        return self.callback()
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 911, in _finalize_pending_conf
        conf = self._conf = self._load_config()
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 921, in _load_config
        self.loader.config_from_object(self._config_source)
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 133, in config_from_object
        self._conf = force_mapping(obj)
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 50, in force_mapping
        if isinstance(m, (LazyObject, LazySettings)):
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 238, in inner
        self._setup()
      File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/home/dorian/Projects/samy/samy_python/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 129, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Also, gunicorn works just fine, so its receiving the environment variable if I dont start the celery program. Also if I set the key to "12345" in the settings.py file, it starts.

Comment: Did you check if the secret key env var is set or not? Maybe try echo $secret_KEY in the terminal.

Comment: That comes up empty. I’m sorry but I thought I was setting the env variable in the supervisor program? Also does it matter if I’m root or not? I run supervisorctl in root

Answer (score 0):

Set the secret_KEY in env like this:

```
export SECRET_KEY="#mysecret_key"
```

And to check:

```
echo $SECRET_KEY
```

And in your django settings,change to:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
```

For detailed reference check: [Read and Set Environment Variables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps)

Comment: Can I remove the environment = secret_KEY from my supervisor config file? Will I ever need to set that again if I restart my server or the web application crashes?

Comment: Yes you can remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the environment variable to the `[program:celery]` section of the supervisor conf file. At the moment it's only set for `gunicorn`.

Comment: Hey thanks andrew. After doing ALOT of reading I realized that its not shared. idk, for some reason I though if gunicorn started first and that environment was running, that celery would just "join". I ended up putting in the key, but then realized that I needed all the env keys. i.e. braintree, google, firebase etc... So now I think I will just read from a json file.